# Columns in html link

Tags: html, css, multiple-columns

I am trying to put a few columns in an html link (so when I hover over the link it selects the entire row). I have something like:

```
<a><span style="width: 400px">test</span> <span style="left:400px">-ing</span></a>
```

but it is not working for me. Is this possible? If so, how do I do it? Thanks!

Comment: `span` is displayed `inline` by default, and as such can not have a `width`. `display:inline-block` f.e. fixes that. And `left` can only work if `position` is not the default `static` (but if you leave the elements in normal flow, you don’t need positioning). In general, you should learn some CSS basics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want?

```
<a><span style="width: 400px; display: inline-block;">test</span> <span style="display: inline-block;">-ing</span></a>
```